# Comparing rows in a table against latest (by date) row in another and inserting or updating based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table (approx 800k rows), '**A**' which for the sake of this post has an Id and a StatusId. Another table '**B**', stores the duration (fromDate and toDate) of a row in **A** maintaining a single status - which is updated once a day.

```
A: id, statusId,

B: idFromA, fromDate, toDate, statusId
```

For instance if we have a row: (id: 123, statusId: 1) which holds onto that statusId for 2 days and then on the 3rd day changes to (id: 123, statusId: 2) then table **B** would be used to record this change.

I need to write the query for this but I'm not sure how you would compare the current statusId of each row in **A** to that of the latest row with the same id in **B** - and then depending on that either insert a new row or extend the toDate (by in this case a day) - any pointers would help

Comment: your B table looks like a "log" table to me. you may want to log the latest status of A to B,  without any checking. Leave the other jobs to the log reading queries.

Comment: @Tim3880 youre right it's a log table, and I get your point. But 800k rows inserted per day seems a lot to me

Comment: So, you want to run a scheduled job that adds a row to table B if the latest record in table B doesn't match the status of table A. Also, you want to update the toDate in the oldest record of table B. Can you please update with an example of what would be in table a and table b before and after you run your script?

Comment: By checking your log table to decide where to update or insert, you will make things worse.  If you care about the size or performance on log-checking queries, you can do a "summarizing" during down time and maintain a "shorter" version of log and truncate the large one.

Comment: I agree, the better way is to follow and audit patter like Jason's answer. Change you log table to be IdFromA, dateOfChange, newStatus... then you can query that to detemine what the status was at any specific date time. But, if you want to stick with what you asked here I can show you how to write that query.

Comment: @PilotBob interesting ideas actually - and yes it looks like the ToDate can go. I read however that using Triggers is a bad idea

Comment: Using triggers isn't universally either bad or good. It "depends". I have developed an HR/Payroll package that does auditing 100% through triggers and it works very well. I have also done apps where the middle tier/data layer does the auditing, writing the audit data in the same transaction as the change using Entity framework for example.

Comment: Make sure you know how triggers work. The thing that trips up many novices is that the trigger fires ONCE for an update. So, if you update 100 rows the trigger will fire once and have to know to deal with 100 row updates.

Comment: @PilotBob I think in my case the long term goal would be to implement proper event driven logging in the code, but for an intermediate solution a daily dump of statuses will be enough. I think the performance hit of triggers is not an option here

Comment: Have you instrumented the performance hit? I bet it will be unmeasurable if all your are doing is an insert into your log table. Also, what happens if you have two changes to the status inbetween you running your script? I will work up the script though and put it in the answer.

Comment: @PilotBob trouble is, that table (A) is central to this business - being one of the most important and heavily accessed tables

Comment: You're still making an assumption that a trigger will hurt you more than the possible inaccurate logging.

Comment: @PilotBob It's possible to have changes in between that are missed but here luckily a general picture will do FOR NOW where a status change that lasts for less than a day is relatively insignificant. Like you say, the long term goal would be to fix the whole system to do logging properly.

Comment: Ok, see my answer. Using a single date simplifies it, and you can still use a query to find the correct row based on your target date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger on TableA to keep TableB in sync.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TableA') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TableA
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    id INT,
    statusId INT
)
IF OBJECT_ID('TableB') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE TableB
CREATE TABLE TableB (
    id INT,
    fromDate DATETIME,
    toDate DATETIME,
    statusId INT
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tg_TableA_statudId
ON TableA AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Update existing values
    UPDATE B SET
        toDate = GETDATE()
    FROM TableB B
        INNER JOIN INSERTED A
            ON A.id = B.id
    WHERE B.toDate IS NULL
        AND B.statusId <> A.statusId

    -- Create new values
    INSERT TableB 
        SELECT id, GETDATE(), NULL, statusId
        FROM INSERTED  A
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM TableB
            WHERE id = A.id
                AND statusId = A.statusId
        )

END
GO

INSERT TableA VALUES (123, 1)
UPDATE TableA SET statusId = 2 WHERE id = 123

SELECT * FROM TableA
SELECT * FROM TableB
```

TableA after testing:

```
id          statusId
----------- -----------
123         2
```

TableB after testing

```
id          fromDate                toDate                  statusId
----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
123         2015-06-19 11:12:42.940 2015-06-19 11:12:42.973 1
123         2015-06-19 11:12:42.993 NULL                    2
```

Comment: It does pretty much what I'm lookg for except through using triggers - i've been told to run away from those...

Comment: Triggers are fine if you use them correctly. Auditing with triggers is very common. Embedding crazy business logic or massive changes within triggers - usually not so good. Like any feature, follow best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way.. rather than using a fromDate and toDate just use a change Date:

```
Insert Into TableB 
(TableA_Id, changeDate, StatusId)
Select Id, GETDATE(), StatusId 
    FROM TableA 
    WHERE TableA.StatusId <> (
        SELECT TOP 1 StatusId 
        FROM TableB 
        WHERE TableB.TableA_Id = TableA.Id 
        Order By changeDate desc
        ) OR NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 StatusId 
        FROM TableB 
        WHERE TableB.TableA_Id = TableA.Id 
        Order By changeDate desc
        )
```

You would have to trigger this fairly often, depending on how often the statusId changes. I still think Jasons way is the better choice. Because, what happens if you now want to log changes to other fields. You have to expand this quite a bit.

Also, depending on how often StatusId changes, you might miss a change if a change happens between two runs of this script.